# Unit Test Events method c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, visual-studio-2013, delegates

How should I unit tests methods like hookUpEvents using only visual studio unit testing framework.

```
public delegate void Mydelegate();

    public event Mydelegate MyEventOne;

    public event Mydelegate MyEventTwo;

    public void hookUpEvents()
    {
        MyEventOne +=  new Mydelegate(UpdateInformationOne);

        MyEventOne +=  new Mydelegate(UpdateInformationTwo);

        MyEventOne +=  new Mydelegate(UpdateLimits);

        MyEventOne += new Mydelegate(UpdateStatus);

        MyEventTwo += new Mydelegate(UpdateInformationThree);
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449197/unit-testing-a-class-with-event-and-delegate

Comment: Test whether the event is raised or not.